# error extra qualification after error use of deleted function

Tags: c++

When implementing a list of hexdirections. I get a couple of errors that says "use of deleted function ...'. After implementing a deleted function

```
HexPolygon& HexPolygon::operator =(const HexPolygon&);
```

I get this error:

```
extra qualification 'HexPolygon::' on member 'operator=' [-fpermissive]
     HexPolygon& HexPolygon::operator =(const HexPolygon&);
```

Well I don't understand this error and it keeps me going around. Could someone help me?

cpp file:

```
QList<HexPolygon> HexDirections =
{
    //[0]NorthEast         //[1] East             //[2]SouthEast
    HexPolygon(1, 0, -1),  HexPolygon(1, -1, 0),  HexPolygon(0, -1, 1),
    //[3]SouthWest         //[4]West              //[5]NorthWest
    HexPolygon(-1, 0, 1),  HexPolygon(-1, 1, 0),  HexPolygon(0, 1, -1)
};

HexPolygon::HexPolygon(int _x, int _y, int _z) :
    cordX(_x), cordY(_y), cordZ(_z)
{
    hexPoints << QPointF(1,0)
              << QPointF(1.5,0.25)
              << QPointF(1.5,0.75)
              << QPointF(1,1)
              << QPointF(0.5,0.75)
              << QPointF(0.5,0.25);
}

HexPolygon::HexPolygon(HexPolygon &&)
{

}

HexPolygon::HexPolygon(const HexPolygon &)
{

}
```

header file:

```
class HexPolygon : public QObject, public QGraphicsPolygonItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit HexPolygon(int, int, int);
    HexPolygon(HexPolygon&&); // error use of deleted funciton
    HexPolygon(const HexPolygon&); // error use of deleted function
    HexPolygon& HexPolygon::operator =(const HexPolygon&); // final error
}
```

Comment: I suspect `Q_OBJECT` imposes some of those limitations.

Comment: Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: Look at the section "No Copy Constructor or Assignment Operator" at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html.

Answer (score 1):

this line in the declaration

```
 HexPolygon& HexPolygon::operator =(const HexPolygon&); // final error
```

should be

```
   HexPolygon& operator=(const HexPolygon&);
```

Just omit "HexPolygon::" in the declaration within HexPolygon class itself.

In the method definition outside the HexPolygon class you would bring HexPolygon:: namespace back:

```
HexPolygon& HexPolygon::operator =(const HexPolygon&)
{
// the implementation 
}
```

I also don't think making that HexPolygon inherit from QObject and QGraphics... is good idea. There are probably some general design issues.
Try too keep it rather simple and maybe using more composition than inheritance.

Like @R Sahu wrote above: those Q_OBJECT within QGraphicsxxx is very suspicious.

Comment: Wel now my programm crased

Comment: Well than there are some other errors too within your classes. If it compiles doesn't mean that it also runs

Comment: Okay that's too bad, but I'm very thankful for the tips. Thank you all.